# ElastiCache (redis) for non default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to create a Redis node, but in the configuration window, I'm not eble to select a VPC I created. All I see is the default VPC. For that reason the subnets are also only the ones that belong to the default VPC.

Is there anything else I need to do in order to get my custom VPC listed, so I can attach an ElastiCache node to it?

Answer (score 19):

Did you create a Cache Subnet Group in you custom VPC?

You need to create a cache subnet in your VPC (inside the ElastiCache Management) first - after that your VPC/Subnet will appear for nodes.